# Exposing spring boot random server port using docker

Tags: docker, spring-boot

We plan to deploy multiple docker images on same VM running same app. In my knowledge, we need to expose webapp port in docker container. But if we plan to use "random" server port in spring boot (using server.port=0), how we expose that random port at run time?

-=-= 
Second question is, does spring boot app picks random port which is available in host VM or just docker container space?

Comment: If you have one application per container, you can use the same port for each of the application. The docker containers have their own separate ports, independent of the host system or other containers. You would then specify the mapping from a host port to the container port when you run the container.

Answer (score 2):

Spring-boot allocate the port at the run time, not at the build time. That means, the port selected by spring boot will not be available until you start the application natively or in the docker container.

Answer to your second question is that Docker pick the port inside the Docker Container. So, practically all the ports will be available other than the ones used by OS.

When combining these two statements, unless you have any specific restrictions, you should specify the port manually to spring-boot application and expose it at `docker run` execution?

Comment: Don't we need to specific port to be exposed, at time of `docker run` command. docker run will start container and at start of container, spring boot app will start.

Comment: I also read somewhere, `net=host` option might work for me. It will expose OS network stack to container env.

Comment: The comment from @dunni is accurate. You can start the app on same port and let docker expose the service on a random port on the host. `docker run -p 3000 my_image` will make docker expose the service in a random port.

Comment: how service discovery works inthis case any pointers for any example for spring boot microservices dockerized with random ports please ?

Comment: @rollingstone In this case, you may have to run a service discovery app like eureka or consul, and call the service name.

Comment: @techtabu yes true but how to make it work in AWS kind if environment. Will service discovery work in AWS?

Comment: I don't have experience in deploying apps in AWS. That said, as long as your services are registered in service discovery app, I don't see a reason why it should not work.